# Rotating Camera Capture for Android in Web View

Tags: android, webview, android-camera, android-orientation

I am capturing an image, storing the data (byte array) in a 2d byte array (the user can take up to five images for this task).  After each capture I am displaying it in a web view.  Even though I take the pic in portrait mode, it loads in the web view in landscape is there anyway to alter this or prevent it from happening?

I have included android:orientation..etc

```
        //Setting Zoom Controls on Web View
         WebPreview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
         WebPreview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
         WebPreview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
         WebPreview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
         WebPreview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
         imageData = PhotoHandler.ImageByteArray[pHandler.counter];
         openJpeg(WebPreview, imageData);

private static void openJpeg(WebView web, byte[] image)
{
    String b64Image = Base64.encodeToString(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String html = String.format(HTML_FORMAT, b64Image);
    web.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
}
```

I'm really unsure what to do and I can't seem to find anything about rotating webview content..

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might have the same problem I have figured out the rotation problem

I converted the byte array to a bitmap, rotated and then converted back to byte array...

```
        Bitmap test = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(IMdata, 0, IMdata.length);

        //Getting Width and Height of Bitmap
        int width = test.getWidth();
        int height = test.getHeight();

        Matrix rotMatrix = new Matrix();

        //Rotating Bitmap * 90 deg
        rotMatrix.postRotate(90);

        //Recreating new Bitmap After Rotation
        Bitmap testRot = Bitmap.createBitmap(receipt, 0,0,width, height, rotMatrix, true);
```

I then converted it back

```
         testRot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);
         byte [] testArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

**EDIT**
I will post the issue about the camera seperately